# C++. Change data member of an Object data member

Tags: c++

This is my simple code to illustrate. There is a Book that has an Author as a data member inside the class.
I want to modify the mail from the Author from the test program, but cppbook.getAuthor().setEmail("...") doesn't work. I tried passing by reference.
I found an alternative but not satisfactory. Must be a simple answer, I think I miss something.

```
class Author {
private:
    string name;
    string email;

public:
    Author(string name, string email) {
       this->name = name;
       this->email = email;
    }

    string getName() {
       return name;
    }

    string getEmail() {
       return email;
    }

    void setEmail(string email) {
       this->email = email;
    }

    void print() {
       cout << name << "-" << email << endl;
    }
};
```

---

```
class Book {
private:
   string name;
   Author author; // data member author is an instance of class Author

public:
    Book(string name, Author author)
          : name(name), author(author) {
    }

    string getName() {
       return name;
    }

    Author getAuthor() {
       return author;
    }

    void print() {
       cout << name << " - " << author.getEmail() << endl;
    }


    void setAuthorMail(string mail) {
       author.setEmail(mail);
    }
};
```

---

```
int main() {
   Author john("John", "john@gmail.com");
   john.print();  // John-john@gmail.com

   Book cppbook("C++ Introduction", john);
   cppbook.print();

   cppbook.getAuthor().setEmail("peter@gmail.com");
   cppbook.print(); //mail doesn't change: C++ Introduction - john@gmail.com
   cppbook.setAuthorMail("andrew@gmail.com");
   cppbook.print(); //mail changes: C++ Introduction - andrew@gmail.com
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/4ct0ip)

Comment: `using namespace std;` in header file is an instant failure. *Doesn't work* means nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *doesn't worrk* is not a valid description of the problem.

Comment: You should try to reduce your code to the relevant stuff. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: @SergeyA What's _not working_ is pretty obvious here. Though the OP could have chosen a better wording or description.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, an essential skill of software developer is an ability to clearly articulate issues. Far more important than knowing a particular language. I want to emphasize this.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to modify the mail from the Author from the test program, but `cppbook.getAuthor().setEmail("...")` doesn't work.

`Author getAuthor();` should be `Author& getAuthor();` if you want to change the internal object associated to `Book`.

Otherwise you're just changing a temporary copy of that `Author` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning objects by value, not by reference. That means, you get a **copy** of author but you're not modifying the one stored in Book class.

You should modify the signature in

```
Author& Book::getAuthor();
```

to make your changes to the object **author** effective